# My footer is creating mini horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

im working in my final proyect to become a Web Developer, and im struggling with my footer, that is creating a minimum horizontal scroll and I cant find why.

I've been doing tests and I can't get rid of that horizontal scroll. An answer as soon as possible would be of great help to me, since this is my final project.

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #111;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    line-height: 4rem;
    color: yellow;
  }
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  li {
    margin: 0 0px;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    &:hover {
      color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
      transition-duration: 1s;
    }
  }
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    a {
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 830px) {
  .socials li {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <h3>KURT BURGERS</h3>
    <ul class="socials">
      <li><a href="https://www.mardelplata.gob.ar/defensadelconsumidor">DEFENSA AL CONSUMIDOR</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.rappi.com.ar/">DELIVERY</a></li>
      <li><a href="paginas/politicasprivacidad.html">POLITICAS DE PRIVACIDAD</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    <p>copyright &copy; <a href="#">KURT BURGERS</a> </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Your snippet lacks a selector for the first set of rules

Comment: When you set a width and have padding, the padding will be added to the width making the width larger than what you set, set `box-sizing: border-box` to that element, then the padding will be added within the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and removed the width:100% from .footer-bottom the horizontal scroll disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the scrollbar is because `footer-bottom`'s width is 100% + the 20px padding you have set for each side of the element. If you add padding to an element with a width, the padding will be added on top of the width unless you set `box-sizing: border-box;`

You could add border-box to footer-bottom as a solution but what you should really do is remove the width 100% from footer-bottom because it is a block element already and it will take up the 100% width by default so there is no need to set it.

The same thing applies to the `ul` `.socials`, it has natural padding on the tag so when you set width 100% to it, it will be wider than 100%. In the case of this `ul`, I simply added `padding: 0`

In the below snippet, I have removed the width 100% from footer-bottom and I added some minor css to `body` so it is easier to see your content width.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #111;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-content h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 4rem;
  color: yellow;
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 0 0px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    font-size: 14px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    a {
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 830px) {
  .socials li {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <h3>KURT BURGERS</h3>
    <ul class="socials">
      <li><a href="https://www.mardelplata.gob.ar/defensadelconsumidor">DEFENSA AL CONSUMIDOR</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.rappi.com.ar/">DELIVERY</a></li>
      <li><a href="paginas/politicasprivacidad.html">POLITICAS DE PRIVACIDAD</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    <p>copyright &copy; <a href="#">KURT BURGERS</a> </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this from your styles:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```